# Will the mass of a stick of dynamite be conserved when it is exploded?

Tags: energy, conservation-laws, mass-energy, physical-chemistry, explosions

> If a stick of dynamite is blown up in a hermetically sealed chamber, the mass of the chamber and fragments, the heat, sound, and light would still be equal to the original mass of the chamber and dynamite. If sitting on a scale, the weight and mass would not change.(Wikipedia)

I was wondering if the chamber cooled down, lost heat, and since energy is equal to mass, will the mass of the chamber decrease?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I thought so, It would decrease. But the total mass would be conserved since the energy released will be absorbed by the surroundings again adding to the mass of the surroundings.

Comment: It takes a lot of energy loss to make a noticeable mass difference. Eg, 1 kw for a day is just under a microgram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. But as @PM 2Ring pointed out the change would be minuscule . Just apply

$$E =mc^2$$ and see for yourself

Hope this helps